# explain where the error on the statment?

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

can someone say what wrong with the bellow stament?

$$
e^{\imath\pi}+1=0\\
e^{\imath\pi}=-1\\
(e^{\imath\pi})^2=(-1)^2\\
e^{2\imath\pi}=1\\
(e^{2\imath\pi})^\imath=1^\imath\\
e^{2\imath^2\pi}=1^\imath\\
e^{-2\pi}=1^\imath
$$

Comment: Taking $\sqrt[i]{\dots}$ on each side of the one-before-last equation. You do this after raising each side to the power of $i$. This is the same as $-1=\sqrt[2]{(-1)^2}=\sqrt[2]{1}=1$.

Comment: @Bacon: No, I misinterpreted that stage. OP doesn't take $\sqrt[i]{\dots}$ on each side, but merely replace $i^2$ with $-1$ on the LHS.

Comment: @barakmanos Oh yes, duly noted and I interpreted it quickly, that way too! Deleted my comment, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong yet.  You didn't write $1^i=1$ at the end of the proof, you left it for the reader to assume.  In the complex plane, $a^b=\exp(b \log a)$ and the logarithm is multivalued unless you are careful with branch cuts.  We have $\log 1=0+2k\pi i$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$.  If we take $k=-1, 1^i=\exp(-2\pi)$ and there is no problem.